# JDToGregorian return 0/0/0 in my hosting server

Tags: php, date, web-hosting, php-ini

I have some issue when using JDToGregorian function in my php script

```
<?php $jd=gregoriantojd(6,20,2007); echo jdtogregorian($jd); ?>
```

return always in my local apache it returns : 6/20/2007
but unfortunately in my remote hosting (1&1) it always returns: 0/0/0

How can I fix the issue please ?

Comment: Are you sure that calendar extensions is installed? PHP compiled with `--enable-calendar`

Comment: Yes, the module calendar is present when I type in the ssh the command "php -m". Is there some include I could add (like jquery include) but for this function (ex: include "jdtogregorian.php") in the top of my php script